# How to apply the Levenshtein distance to a set of target strings?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, mathematical-optimization

- Let `TARGET` be a set of strings that I expect to be spoken.
- Let `SOURCE` be the set of strings returned by a speech recognizer (that is, the possible sentences that it has heard).

I need a way to choose a string from `TARGET`. I read about the *Levenshtein distance* and the *Damerau-Levenshtein distance*, which basically returns the distance between a source string and a target string, that is the number of changes needed to transform the source string into the target string.

But, how can I apply this algorithm to a set of target strings?

I thought I'd use the following method:

1. For each string that belongs to `TARGET`, I calculate the distance from each string in `SOURCE`. In this way we obtain an *m-by-n* matrix, where n is the cardinality of `SOURCE` and n is the cardinality of `TARGET`. We could say that the i-th row represents the similarity of the sentences detected by the speech recognizer with respect to the i-th target.
2. Calculating the average of the values ​​on each row, you can obtain the average distance between the i-th target and the output of the speech recognizer. Let's call it `average_on_row(i)`, where `i` is the row index.
3. Finally, for each row, I calculate the standard deviation of all values in the row. For each row, I also perform the sum of all the standard deviations. The result is a column vector, in which each element (Let's call it `stadard_deviation_sum(i)`) refers to a string of `TARGET`.

The string which is associated with the shortest `stadard_deviation_sum` could be the sentence pronounced by the user. Could be considered the correct method I used? Or are there other methods?
Obviously, too high values ​​indicate that the sentence pronounced by the user probably does not belong to `TARGET`.

Comment: As Ali points out, Levenshtein doesn't seem like a good solution here. The edit distance between 'what' and 'hat' is only 1, but they sound quite distinct - English is full of such examples. The good news is that if you can find a good equivalent for phonemes, you can use the same algorithms to find the closest match.

Comment: @NickJohnson: I read about _soundex_, but it is only available for English.

Comment: Metaphone is a newer and more accurate algorithm; I think there are non-English variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate these probabilities first: probability of insertion, deletion and substitution. Then use log of these probabilities as penalties for each operation.

In a "context independent" situation, if pi is probability of insertion, pd is probability of deletion and ps probability of substitution, the probability of observing the same symbol is pp=1-ps-pd.

In this case use log(pi/pp/k), log(pd/pp) and log(ps/pp/(k-1)) as penalties for insertion, deletion and substitution respectively, where k is the number of symbols in the system.

Essentially if you use this distance measure between a source and target you get log probability of observing that target given the source. If you have a bunch of training data (i.e. source-target pairs) choose some initial estimates for these probabilities, align source-target pairs and re-estimate these probabilities (AKA EM strategy).

You can start with one set of probabilities and assume context independence. Later you can assume some kind of clustering among the contexts (eg. assume there are k different sets of letters whose substitution rate is different...).

Comment: What do you mean by "number of symbols in the system"? Maybe a character?

Comment: For example if we are talking about DNA sequences, the number of symbols is 4, for english words it is 26 (ignoring numeric and other characters).

Comment: @enzom83 I have mostly applied this on DNA sequences, but should work on your data also. I have also added some implementation details. Hope this helps!

Comment: Regarding the probability of observing the same symbol, the probability of insertion is not present in `pp` because the possible insertion of a character does not determine the loss of the symbol. Is that correct? Moreover, if I wanted to also consider the transposition of two adjacent characters, should I simply consider an additional probability `pt` as probability of transposition? In this last case, would I get `pp = 1-pd-ps-pt` as probability of observing the same symbol and `log(pt/pp)` as penalty for transposition?

Comment: @enzom83 Yes. Insertion does not affect the presence of that particular letter. Also, I assumed that deletion and substitution are mutually exclusive event, but not insertion. Regarding transposition, if you think transposition is mutually exclusive w.r.t deletion and substitution your calculations are correct. But, if that is not the case, then you should modify accordingly (calculations might become much more hairier!).

Comment: Well, so `-log(pi/pp/k)`, `-log(pd/pp)`, `-log(ps/pp/(k-1))` and `-log(pt/pp)` could be some sort of weight for insertion, deletion, substitution and transposition respectively, then I might change the basic algorithm by adding these weights.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert but your proposal does not make sense. First of all, in practice I'd expect the cardinality of TARGET to be very large if not infinite. Second, I don't believe the Levensthein distance or some similar similarity metric will be useful.

If :

- you could really define SOURCE and TARGET sets,
- all strings in SOURCE were equally probable,
- all strings in TARGET were equally probable,
- the strings in SOURCE and TARGET consisted of not characters but phonemes,

then I believe your best bet would be to find the pair p in SOURCE, q in TARGET such that distance(p,q) is minimum. Since especially you cannot guarantee the equal-probability part, I think you should think about the problem from scratch, do some research and make a completely different design. The usual methodology for speech recognition is the use Hidden Markov models. I would start from there.

**Answer to your comment:** Choose whichever is more probable. If you don't consider probabilities, it is hopeless.

[Suppose the following example is on phonemes, not characters]

Suppose the recognized word the "chees". Target set is "cheese", "chess". You must calculate P(cheese|chees) and P(chess|chees) What I'm trying to say is that not every substitution is equiprobable. If you will model probabilities as distances between strings, then at least you must allow that for example d("c","s") < d("c","q") . (It is common to confuse c and s letters but it is not common to confuse c and q) Adapting the distance calculation algorithm is easy, coming with good values for all pairs is difficult.

Also you must somehow estimate P(cheese|context) and P(chess|context) If we are talking about board games chess is more probable. If we are talking about dairy products cheese is more probable. This is why you'll need large amounts of data to come up with such estimates. This is also why Hidden Markov Models are good for this kind of problem.

Comment: In the case I analyzed, the `TARGET` is not very large, and the `SOURCE` is returned to me by a speech recognizer that is already implemented and so I just use it. Ok for the minimum distance between p and q, but if the minimum distance is the same for two (or more) strings in `TARGET`, which I choose between these?

Comment: Good answer, now if simply calculating distance(source,target) is sufficient (it could be, if size of TARGET is sufficiently small). When one or more distances are the same, you can use probability of source returned by speech recognizer to determine the winner. 

This is probably the best you can do without going into constructing your own probability models.

Comment: @AliFerhat: Great! Now I understand why we must consider the probabilities. Thanks for your additional answer!